# SWT statusText change when mouse no longer hovering over link

Tags: java, browser, swt

I am creating a web browser with SWT and am having trouble with the status text listener. It updates when the mouse hovers over a link but does not update when the mouse is no longer over a link.

I tried calling "updateListeners" within a mouseMoved listener however the statusText listener is only implemented as a typed listener and i don't believe can be updated since there is no SWT.StatusText constant. I don't believe this would have worked anyway, since internally were the status text updated when the mouse left a link it would probably change and call its own changed function.

Any suggestions? I would prefer not to use javascript (but will if necessary), and I am running SWT from source should something need to be changed internally.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show some working code. Its hard to say whats happening and what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm pretty sure this is normal behavior for the status text listener. It behaved this way in both the example code I got online and my own code (i'm running ubuntu 12.04), I was wondering how to augment that behavior. However, I have since realized that the SWT browser isn't going to cut it for the project i'm working on and have switched to Qt. I was prejudiced against Qt since it isn't very lightweight, but I needed something feature rich and cross platform, and SWT browser didn't offer the functionality i need.